# PHP's time and date comparison not working using date()

Tags: php, date

I want to add validation rule to my input form so people can't pick a date higher then today but for some reason my operators are not working like they should... at least I don't think they are

```
//plain use of comparison operators
$a = 4; $b = 4;
if($a <= $b) { echo "umm?"; } // this return true

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$today = date("d/m/y");

if(!empty($date['dateA']) && (date($date['dateA']) <= $today)) {
```

now the last `if` statement is getting `$today` value in the same format as `$date` arrays format.

Here is what's driving me nutz... if:

```
$today = 08/02/2015
```

`$date = 07/02/2015` returns true
`$date = 08/02/2015` returns false why isn't this returning `true`?

When I'm using `<=` to make sure that `$date` can't be higher then `$today`, then why won't `$date <= $today` not return `true` when they've got the same values?
as far as I know it acts more or less like `$date < $today`

Also, I've tried using `strtotime` instead of date for `$date` but it still acts the same....

So what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why should you ever stick to string comparison. I recommend using mathematical operation with mathematical numbers.

do this:

```
if(strtotime($date) < time())
{
   // then allow doing something
}
```

`strtotime()` converts a date-string you already have (example: `"22/5/2014"`) to an integer timestamp. `time()` also returns timestamp of today. Then, you can use these both numbers to do your operations.

While the above fully works, you can also utilize Date Object in PHP which is very precise and implicitly calculates things such as Leap Year etc.

Example from PHP's Documentaion:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Read More here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

Currently it checks for a lower day number first, when it should be checking the year first, because string comparison checks 1 character at a time, left to right.

You can store the date format in year/month/day to fix this, but it's kinda ugly doing that.

I would recommend using timestamps, this is the amount of seconds since 1970 1st Jan 00:00:00 GMT, and can be retrieved in PHP via calling time() which gives the current timestamp. You can retrieve the timestamp for a certain date via calling strtotime().

Comment: umm could your give me an example of using this?
also i dont see why i'd have to use that....
$today = date("d/m/y")
and it returns it as 08/02/2015 
so its in the same format as the dates in my $date array which is filled by a date picker as d/m/y...

so when i write as the if statement above shouldn't it just start comparing like this?:
$today 08/02/2015
$date 08/02/2015
0 <= 0 = true
8 <= 8 = true
0 <= 0 = true
2 <= 2 = true
and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using string comparison, which is not a recommended way to compare dates. Still, I don't know why the equality check is failing, but I think you should use DateTime objects instead: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php (ONLY if you use PHP >= 5.2.2, because the PHP manual says DateTime comparison does not work correctly in previous versions)

In your case the last line would become:
`if(!empty($date['dateA']) && DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date['dateA']) <= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $today))`

Comment: i ended up using  if(!empty($date['dateA']) && date($date['dateA']) <= date('d/m/Y')) {      is there any downsides to using it like this instead of strtotime or datetime::createfromformat?

Comment: Where did you find the `date()` function? I recommend you read its manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
The first parameter of this function is a _format_ (e.g. "dd-mm-YYYY"), not a date. And the return value is a string, which means that we're back to the initial problem of string comparison if you use the `date()` function.
`strtotime()` returns an int, which is good for comparison, but it is less flexible as it expects an English date format.

Comment: i tried using your code but it returned null for $date, then i tried using strtotime for both $date and $today but for some reason it ended up giving me 2 diffrent numbers.... perhaps because $date is an or array or perhaps because its filled by a date picker but i went over the date picker serve times and the format its outputting is *dd/mm/yyyy* just as date('d/m/Y'), i echoed both and they both sent out the right format....
and then just for fun (not for anything i read anyware) i tried date($date['dateA']) 
and it worked perfectly with "<=" so...

Comment: I noticed just now that the date format was incorrect in my answer (it's now corrected), I was using `dd-mm-YYYY` whereas your dates use `dd/mm/YYYY`, but I assume you noticed that and tried the correct format. However, you say you tried my code with `$date` but shouldn't it be `$date['dateA']` just like in your original code?

Comment: i did use it with the original code $date['dateA'] just forgot to write it sry, and thanks i'll try your new code out :D

Comment: when you first posted your dateTime:createfromformat i saw right away that they were blinded together with - instead of / but its not working for me. no matter how i use your code it returns true also for a day above todays date.
last update is that i got it working my self with more or less no problems with this code "date($date[7]) <= date('Y/m/d'))" exploding the $date['dateA'] and imploding it like yyyy/mm/dd, i realised a huge flaw in this if a user inputs the date like d/m/yy = 1/3/15 it will return true how would i go about breaking this down and change it to dd/mm/yyyy = 01/03/2015.

Comment: also i really appreciate the time you've taken to try and help me so far! THANKS :) 
do you have any idea why your DateTime aint working for me and just outputting true in cases it should be false?

Comment: Oops, my bad! My date format was wrong, I must have gotten confused with some other language. See above my corrected answer (tested, this time... it works), there are no repeated letters so it's `d/m/Y`.

About the "1/3/15" user input example, I thought that createFromFormat() would be smart and accept it as well, but it doesn't. You could get away using the `j/n/y` format, but then that no longer parses "01/03/2015" correctly.

My best guess for now would be to use a regular expression (see doc for `preg_replace()`) to either restrict or alter the user input so as to get the format you want.

Comment: hello tanguyP. thanks for all your help your solution helped find an overall solution both for user input as 1/1/15 and date picker input 01/01/2015 i just run the date from the array thru an if and else if that checks the length of the strings and then change it to the correct format. so Thanks a lot i couldn't have done this without your help :D